# Can I tweak the Sentry Replay config without re-deploying my React app?

Tags: reactjs, sentry

I know that by using Sentry `Loader Script` I can enable/disable some Sentry features on the fly, but can I also adjust some config (like `replaysSessionSampleRate` and `replaysOnErrorSampleRate`) without re-deploying?

I checked this page documentation but apparently, ts says nothing about tweaking the Sentry.init() values itself on the fly

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/loader/

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the SDK config from within Sentry is currently not possible.